# named slot and slot-scope vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How to move from slot and slot-scope in vue 3. Currently, the update and delete buttons don't work.

//CODE//

```
 **<template slot="cell(action)" slot-scope="data">**
        <b-button size="sm" variant="primary" :to="{ name:'editarProductos', params:id_producto: data.item.id} }">
    Editar
    </b-button>
    <b-button size="sm" variant="danger" :to="{ name:'eliminarProductos', params: {id_producto:data.item.id} }">
    Eliminar
    </b-button>
    </template>
```

Comment: `slot-scope` was already deprecated in Vue2: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots-with-the-slot-scope-Attribute

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation here: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html

We no longer need to define slot-scoped. We can define a slot like:-

**Normal Defination:**

`<slot></slot>`

**Usage:**

`<Component> slot content </Component>`

**Named Slots:**

`<slot name="customSlot"></slot>`

Usage:

```html
<Component> 
  <template #customSlot> Custom Content </template>
</Component>
```